# elasticsearch php api Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException

Tags: php, apache, elasticsearch

I have the following PHP script:

```
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();
$params = [
    'index'  => 'my_index',
    'type'   => 'My_type',
    'id'     => 'AVlV2YcFAEkAZoTQQTlH'
];
var_dump( $client->get($params));
```

When I run the script through the command line using `php a.php` it works fine
but when I visit the page at http://localhost/a.php when it is running with Apache, I recieve the following error:

```
Type: Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException
Message: No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a network(firewall) issue.

run this command:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

**SELinux doesn't allow  httpd daemon to talk to the elastic service.**